# How to change PPA to point to another distro

Tags: doublecmd

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04, I want to install doublecmd (Double Commander). I've added the PPA, but when I update its looking at dists/raring/main.

Its not there, but it's on Precise.

How could I do to make it look in `precise` directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First open Software Properties

- Software Center>Edit>Software Sources
- Then go to the Other Software tab and click the Edit button on the PPA you want
  to edit.
  [image]
- Change the Distribution name and Accept. Then update your repositories running `sudo apt-get update`. You should be able to install the package now.